# MS-Access database help needed

Tags: ms-access

I am a beginner in using Access.  In the past I used a database where I could select a beginning and ending date on a calendar, and the query would bring back all items that would "occur" during those dates. I would like to replicate that database.

The records would need to be pulled based on their frequency- for example I have items that occur on a monthly (on a certain date), weekly (on a certain day), bi-weekly (every other day of the week).  (There are codes to represent this- for example PPBR would be every other Thursday; PPM23 would be the 23rd of each month; PPWT would be weekly every Tuesday). Like setting up a reoccurring appointment in outlook, these items would also continue for future dates so that I know when they need to occur next by just clicking on the calendar.

For example, on Tuesday June 23rd, all items that occur every other Tuesday, items for the 23rd and weekly on Tuesday should all be pulled into one report.

I have created a table for the main record info.  I have also created a separate table listing all the variations of the frequency (code and day of week/date they occur) and have linked them.

I am stuck at this point as to how to create and incorporate the calendar function and would appreciate any assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: With lots and lots of code. A calender type db is not easy to build. Have you read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056?

Comment: Also, http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=45047&highlight=calendar

Answer (score 0):

June7's comments direct you to ask a more focused question.  I gather that you are simply asking how to incorporate "calendar functionality", but your detailed description muddles your intention.

Since you've create something like this before, I presume that the "calendar" you mean is simply the calendar-style date picker already available with the TextBox controls.  In that case, you could add two unbound TextBox controls --one for the beginning date and one for the ending date-- and set the following properties in the Property Sheet:

- **Format**: Short Date
- **Show Date Picker**: for dates
- **After Update**:  [Event Procedure]

With the **Show Date Picker** property enabled, upon clicking inside the TextBox control a little Calendar icon is displayed.  Clicking on that icon shows a pop-up date picker.

In the TextBox_AFterUpdate event handlers add code to update the Form's RecordSource with an appropriate query.  (It would also be possible to refer to the TextBox values directly in a query, but your description of the date criteria sounds too complicated to handle in a single query directly.)